# Possible to handle multi character delimiter in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I have `[~]` as my delimiter for some csv files I am reading.

```
1[~]a[~]b[~]dd[~][~]ww[~][~]4[~]4[~][~][~][~][~]
```

I have tried this

```
val rddFile = sc.textFile("file.csv")
val rddTransformed = rddFile.map(eachLine=>eachLine.split("[~]"))
val df = rddTransformed.toDF()
display(df)
```

However this issue with this, is that it comes as a single value array with `[` and `]` in each field. So the array would be

```
["1[","]a[","]b[",...]
```

I can't use

```
val df = spark.read.option("sep", "[~]").csv("file.csv")
```

Because multi-character seperator is not supported.  What other approach can I take?

```
1[~]a[~]b[~]dd[~][~]ww[~][~]4[~]4[~][~][~][~][~]
2[~]a[~]b[~]dd[~][~]ww[~][~]4[~]4[~][~][~][~][~]
3[~]a[~]b[~]dd[~][~]ww[~][~]4[~]4[~][~][~][~][~]
```

Edit - this is not a duplicate, the duplicated thread is about multi delimiters, this is multi-character single delimiter

Comment: the rdd map isn't working because `split` takes a regex. If you escape the `[` and `]` with backticks it will work: `.split("\\[~\\]")`

Comment: @Tim Thanks. Is there a way to translate the array to actual different columns? (Note: The number of columns is completely arbitrary for the file and unknown before hand)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").load("inputpath")
df.rdd.map(i => i.mkString.split("\\[\\~\\]")).toDF().show(false)
```

try below

for your another requirement

```
val df1 = df.rdd.map(i => i.mkString.split("\\[\\~\\]").mkString(",")).toDF()
val iterationColumnLength = df1.rdd.first.mkString(",").split(",").length
df1.withColumn("value",split(col("value"),",")).select((0 until iterationColumnLength).map(i => col("value").getItem(i).as("col_" + i)): _*).show
```

[image]

Comment: The issue with this is the same to what I used `rddFile.map(eachLine=>eachLine.split("\\[\\~\\]"))`, (when correctly escaping the split characters) split returns an array and gets pushed into a single column of array type, instead of splitting it into separate columns.

Comment: updated the answer to convert one column to multiple

Comment: `df1.withColumn("value",explode(col("value"))).withColumn("index", lit(1)).groupBy("index").pivot("value").sum("index").filter(col("index") =!= 1).drop("index", "").show` This portion returned a blank dataframe.  `df1` had a large amount of records, but the following transformation seemed to only produce an empty dataframe.

Comment: That’s correct. But you have no rows correct. Could you please send the exact test data. The code only convert your array of one column to multiple column in basis of number of values in array. Please send your file.csv with few sample records

Comment: I updated OP with test data that's not working. I have multiple rows.  However, even if the test data was only 1 row, it should still work.

Comment: Updated as per your requirement. Please check

Comment: Hey, I have one more quick question, I do not think this would be possible, but I have a predefined `schema` object.  Generally I would do `spark.read.option("sep", ",").option("badRecordsPath", badRecordLoc).schema(schema).csv(inputLoc)`.  By passing a schema with bad record path, it would put rows with the incorrect number of columns in the bad record location.    Would it be possible to add this to your implementation? I'm assuming not possible.

Comment: @testacc I would suggest to filter out those rows on basis of the condition. You may not use this option as above

Comment: I noted it did not entirely work.